# Does intern testing framework have any gulp plug-ins or docs to integrate with gulp?

Tags: gulp, intern

Does intern testing framework have 
any gulp plug-ins or docs to integrate with gulp?

Comment: Any dojo or intern.io contributors have thoughts on this?

Answer (score 5):

it doesn't look like it but I've done this
using gulp-shell :

```
gulp.task('intern', shell.task([
    'node_modules/intern/bin/intern-client.js config=tests/intern'
]));
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I just found [gulp-intern](https://github.com/stimms/gulp-intern) on github. Haven't tested it yet, though.